# How do I pass the quantities and prices of individual items to PayPal?

Tags: html, paypal, shopping-cart

I'm currently taking a beginner's web design class. I wanted to expand upon a project we just did where we designed a site for a store and build a simple shopping cart using HTML and CSS and using PayPal to check out using a Sandbox account. I've already created a business Sandbox account and built the cart table with a list of items for purchase and number input forms for users to enter the quantity. My question is, how do I pass the individual quantities of the items and prices to the paypal cart?

Answer (score 1):

Check the [shopping cart items section of the variables reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HH0D0TA).  You'll notice fields that have a 'x' on the end of them.  Those would be 1,2,3,etc. for each individual item.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd method on that page should help you setting that up : https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/howto_checkout-outside